# How to configure Apache with ProxyPass to IIS application running Windows Authentication

Tags: apache, windows-authentication, iis-8.5, proxypass

I run both Apache2.2 and IIS 8.5 on a Windows 2012 R2 Server. The reason why I need both is because there is an old Ruby on rails application running on Apache and a .NET MVC 4 application on IIS.
**My problem appear when I'm trying to setup a virtual host to the .NET application when the Authentication mode is Windows Authentication**. If I use Anonymous Authentication mode everything works as I expect. The issue is that the authentication promt show up for each request (all static files, js, css etc).
Is there a way to work around?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#Default
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:\Apache2\htdocs
</VirtualHost>

#Ruby on Rails App
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.local
  ServerAlias railsapp.mydomain.local

  DocumentRoot C:\rails\railsapp\public

  <Location "C:\rails\railsapp\public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Location>

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:2005/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2005/
</VirtualHost>

# .NET MVC App
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.local
  ServerAlias mvcapp.mydomain.local

  <Location "D:\Webfiles\MvcApp\MvcApp.Web\Content">
    Options FollowSymLinks 
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Location>

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:2012/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2012/  
</VirtualHost>
```